# How to save (Quartz Scheduler) trigger and job in mySQL db?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

My current project is in spring version 1.5.x so I am unable to use the following dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, I tried using the below dependency and although I am able to schedule a job and run it at the scheduled time. But as per my use case I need to store that trigger information in mySQL database. Whereas using the above dependency I am able to do the job but upgrading the framework's version is out of scope.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting while using spring-boot-starter-quartz dependency, in essence both dependencies work in similar fashion.

Comment: Also for the use case, you can simply put the cron expression in the DB and when you are initializing the scheduler you can use the same. However, beware, if you change the cron expression later in DB, do not expect the scheduler to run automatically in the new schedule. You need to reinitialize the scheduler once more.